# Simplicial complexes embedded on a compact manifold

Tags: graph-theory, riemannian-geometry, simplicial-complex, compact-manifolds

Every finite graph can be embedded on some compact surface of sufficient genus such that no two edges cross.  If $S$ is a finite simplicial complex of dimension $n$, can $S$ be embedded in some compact Riemann Manifold of dimension $n+1$ such that no two simplices intersect?

Comment: Hint: If a complex $X$ embeds in a $k$-dimensional manifold then each link in $X$ embeds in the sphere $S^{k-1}$.

Comment: So if a complex X embeds in a $k$-dimensional manifold and contains $L$ links, then it can be embedded in ${\prod_{i=1}^{L} S^{k-1}}$?  My apologies if I got your hint incorrect

Comment: No, the hint  is that you have an obstruction to embedding of a simplicial complex $X$ in a $k$-dimensional manifold coming from topology of the links of $X$. Do you know of any obstructions to embeddings of simplicial complexes into spheres? For instance, embeddings of graphs into $S^2$? Can you translate the latter to an obstruction for embedding of a 2d complex into a 3-manifold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the complete story:

1. Let $X$ be a (finite, although, it is not really necessary) $k$-dimensional simplicial complex. Then $X$ always embeds in some (smooth) manifold $M$ of dimension $2k$. To sketch a proof of this: $X$ can be immersed (one needs to define what this means) in $R^{2k}$ (this is a form of Whitney's immersion theorem). Then pull-back of a regular neighborhood of the image of this immersion yields the desired manifold $M$.
2. For each $k$, there exists a finite   $k$-dimensional simplicial complex which does not embed in any manifold of dimension $2k-1$. A specific example is given by the $k$-fold product of copies of the "tripod" $T$, which is the unique finite tree with four vertices, one of which (the "center") has valence 3. Let $v\in T$ be this center. The key to the proof is that the link $L$ of a vertex of $X$  corresponding to $(v,...,v)$ is isomorphic to the $k$-fold join of the copies of the set on 3 elements. This complex is known not to admit embeddings in $S^{2k-2}$ (this result is due to van Kampen). However, if $X$ embeds in a manifold of dimension $n$, the links of vertices of $X$ embed in the sphere $S^{n-1}$. Hence, $X$ does not embed in any $2k-1$-dimensional manifold.

The simplest example that you can work out by hand is the product $X=T\times T$. The link of $(v,v)$ in $X$ is the complete bipartite graph $K_{3,3}$. The latter does not embed in $S^2$ (this is an application of the Jordan curve theorem), hence, $X$ does not embed in any 3-dimensional manifold.

*Shapiro, Arnold*, [**Obstructions to the imbedding of a complex in a euclidean space. I: The first obstruction**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1969998), Ann. Math. (2) 66, 256-269 (1957). [ZBL0085.37701](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0085.37701).

*Van Kampen, E. R.*, [**Komplexe in euklidischen Räumen**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02940628), Abhandlungen Hamburg 9, 72-78 (1932). [ZBL58.0615.02](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:58.0615.02).

*Wu, Wen-tsün*, A theory of imbedding, immersion, and isotopy of polytopes in a Euclidean space, Peking: Science Press. xv, 291 pp. (1965). [ZBL0177.26402](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0177.26402).